# embed google docs in wordpress site

Tags: wordpress

I want to embed editable google docs in my wordpress site. I try different plugins but it not give option for edit.
How i can embed google docs in wordpress.so that user can edit and view the docs.i want to embed editable google docs in wordpress site.

Comment: Asking for recommendations is off-topic, please read [ask] and [help/on-topic]. See [this](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/58374/12615) for a solution.

Answer (score 1):

Create your Google doc document then make sure all people are able to edit the document without logging in. 
To do this click share on the upper right hand corner of the page when you've opened the document and then try changing the "who can access" from private to "anyone with the link".
Now simply publish the document on the web, get the embedded code and simply paste it in your blog post.
I think this should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

I've been working on this for a while. An iframe works well for editing/viewing on desktop. The plugins are good for viewing documents. When it comes to mobile browsers, iframes don't fly. Its best for the user to download the document and then view it on a native google docs app.